# How to monitor virtual machine log files in Azure

Tags: azure, service, azure-functions, virtual-machine

Does Azure provide service for reading custom log files from virtual machines and visualizing it. For example reading boot.log from linux virtual machine and show latest 10 rows in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Custom Logs** data source in **Azure Monitor** allows you to collect events from text files on both Windows and Linux computers. Many applications log information to text files instead of standard logging services such as Windows Event log or Syslog. Once collected, you can either parse the data into individual fields in your queries or extract the data during collection to individual fields.

Please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-sources-custom-logs) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Boot info are included on Vm once you created it this option.
[Bot log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgcbF.png)

Custom logs could be extrated with OMS agent also, at least few moths ago, with Diagnostic extension Agent [Overview agents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgcbF.png). The main diference beteween both is the place where data is sent: Azure Storage or Azure Monitor